# C# UnassignedReferenceException:

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

in the code (https://livebook.manning.com/book/unity-in-action-third-edition/chapter-3/166), when adding the ability to attack the enemy with fireballs, the files are compiled, and when you start the game and meet the enemy, an error occurs:

```
UnassignedReferenceException: The variable fireballPrefab of WanderingAI has not been assigned.
You probably need to assign the fireballPrefab variable of the WanderingAI script in the inspector.
UnityEngine.Object.Instantiate[T] (T original) (at <e8a406da998549af9a2680936c7da25a>:0)
WanderingAI.Update () (at Assets/WanderingAI.cs:31)
```

object added
https://prnt.sc/hudEm5hvcuWx

```
   void Update()
    {   
        if (_alive) 
        {
            transform.Translate(0, 0, speed * Time.deltaTime);
            Ray ray = new Ray(transform.position, transform.forward); // непрерывное движение
            RaycastHit hit;
            if (Physics.SphereCast(ray, 0.75f, out hit)) // бросаем луч с описанной вокруг него окружностью
        {   GameObject hitObject = hit.transform.gameObject;
            if (hitObject.GetComponent<PlayerCharacter>()) 
            {
                if (_fireball == null) 
                {
                    _fireball = Instantiate(fireballPrefab) as GameObject;
                    _fireball.transform.position = transform.TransformPoint(Vector3.forward * 1.5f);
                    _fireball.transform.rotation = transform.rotation;
                }
            }
            else if (hit.distance < obstacleRange) 
            {
                float angle = Random.Range (-110, 110); // поворот с наполовину случайным выбором направления
                transform.Rotate(0, angle, 0);
            }
        }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `The variable fireballPrefab of WanderingAI has not been assigned.`  Assign the prefab.

Comment: how to do it? there is a screenshot of object binding in the question

Comment: Drag the prefab into the fireballPrefab slot from the inspector.

Comment: object added https://prnt.sc/hudEm5hvcuWx    problem still exists

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you've added to the script, not the prefab containing the script.

Select prefab containing your WanderingAI script in the editor, assign value in the inspector. It should be fine then.

If you do not have prefab with this script and simply adding it via `AddComponent` method, you have to pass link to the needed prefab explixitly after creation.

Answer (score 0):

Ah I think now I see it: You only assigned the prefab as **"default reference"** directly on the script import settings itself.

This only has an effect if using `AddComponent` now **after** assigning this default reference. If you already had an instance of your component attached to an object in your scene it won't be affected by this afterwards added default reference

=> Find the object in the hierarchy this component is actually attached to and assign the prefab there via the Inspector as well!